# Using a disjunction in split

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In Google Spreadsheets, sometimes I need to split a value at the point at which it has a ".", while other times I need the split to occur at "_" or "-".  Does split support the logical disjunction?

I have the following in my script:

```
var str=val[i][0].split(".")
```

The following does not work:

```
var str=val[i][0].split((".")||("-")||("_"))
```

My purpose is to create a list of names from e-mails that are either in the firstname.lastname@email.com, firstname_lastname@email.com, or firstname-lastname@email.com format.

I have not found instruction [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).  I am self-taught.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
function test_Split()
{
  var str = 'aaa-bbb.ccc_ddd';
  Logger.log(str.split(/[.\-_]/)); // [aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd]
}
```

As you see, a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) may be used to split a string.

- `[]` to include any char
- `\-` is to escape a hyphen.

Please see more on split function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) (your link ;).